# save result of an async function in a variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using an async function to get data from a collection in firebase:`

```
let teste = async function getDados(db)
{
  const snapshot = await db.collection('place').doc('House').collection('user').get();
  snapshot.forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key.id, '=>', key.data());
});
return snapshot
}

console.log("test", teste)
```

however, when displaying the variable, the result is:

**test [AsyncFunction: getDados]**

How do I save the result that is displayed in the console.log in the function, in a variable?

Thank you!
The final code:

```
async function getDados(db)
{
  const snapshot = await db.collection('place').doc('House').collection('user').get();
  let results = [];
  snapshot.forEach((key) => {
    results.push(key.id, key.data());
    console.log(key.id, '=>', key.data());  
  });
  return results
}

async function teste2()
{
let teste = await getDados(db);

console.log("test", teste);
}

teste2();
```

Comment: You didn't *call* the function -- add parentheses to `teste()`. Secondly, when you *do* call it, you will get a Promise object.

Answer (score 1):

You did in fact did not call the function. You could try something like,

```
async function getDados(db)
{
  let results = [];
  const snapshot = await db.collection('place').doc('House').collection('user').get();
  snapshot.forEach((key) => {
  results.push(key.id);
  console.log(key.id, '=>', key.data());
});
return results;
}

const teste = await getDados(db);
console.log("results ", teste);
```

I'm not sure about the `key.data()` portion of your code, so I just referenced `key.id`

Comment: But `async` functions return a promise - this will not log `snapshot` as returned from within `teste`.

Comment: Thank you! the result returned: test Promise {<pending>}

Do you know how I can get this data from the promise?

Comment: Try with `console.log("results ",await teste());`

Comment: a syntax error is shown.
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

Comment: Right, that function is waiting for at least one `db` argument. I've edited the snipet @FilipeDias

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the function `getDados` inside the variable `teste`, then if you use `typeof teste` the result will be `function`. You can call the function `getDados` with `teste(db)`, but if you want to store the return of `getDados` inside the variable `teste` you can use the following code:

```js
async function getDados(db)
{
  const snapshot = await db.collection('place').doc('House').collection('user').get();

  snapshot.forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key.id, '=>', key.data());
  });
  return snapshot
}

let teste = await getDados(db);

console.log("test", teste);
```

Remember to use `await` inside an `async` function if your project uses Node on version prior to v14.3.0, which supports top-level await.